# Oracle schema validator

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Oracle DB in my application

My Application allow the user to create schema and for that reason

I want to do some validation before my application is set up..

for example I want to make sure that the user didn't create table with long column name

(There is limitation in Oracle for max 30 bytes table and column name)

I holding Dialect object in my validation function ,

Is it possible using the dialect object to find out that the user input (in my example column name)

is not correct - (because the column name size is more than 30 bytes..)

please assist,

Thanks,

Jhon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it ..

I declared new object of class : java.sql.DatabaseMetaData

in This class there is getMaxColumnNameLength() method which return the limit for each DB

(for example in oracle that method return 30)

and now I can do my validation!

Thanks anyway :)

John.